# How to typehint dataclass field in function signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, typing, python-dataclasses

I've a frozen dataclass with some constants and function, which accept any constant from this class as it's argument.
How can I typehint this mechanic? I need to tell user that function waits for any field's value from this specific dataclass.
It should looks like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Consts:
    const_0: int = 0
    const_1: int = 1
    const_2: int = 2
    const_3: int = 3


def foo(param: Consts.field):
    return param
```

**UPD**:
According to @JaredSmith hint I've tried to use Enum. It look like much correct. But the problem still exists.
I've tried to use `typing.Literal`, like this:

```
def foo(param: Literal[Consts.const_0, Consts.const_1]):
    return param
```

but it will not give use a correct typehint. In case `foo(Consts)` we will get this, not pretty obvious, warning: `Expected type 'Consts', got 'Type[Consts]' instead`  instead of something like that: `Expected type Consts.value got Consts instead`

So, the main question, after updates, is: How to aggregate constants in logical groups in the code to simplify their usage (dataclass or Enum) and how to typehint the corresponding solution.

**UPD**:
Great thanks for all comments. They showed me lot of interesting facts. As an answer for current question I choose IntEnum variant by @JaredSmith. Also, thanks @chepner and @InSync for the deep explanation.

Comment: If you want an enum, use an enum rather than trying to morph a dataclass into one https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/enum.html. If you're expecting user input to be compared against it, you probably specifically want an IntEnum.

Comment: @JaredSmith this seems to be a worthy solution. But, after typehinting like "Consts.value" I can't get a type-warning. IDE thinks that function waits for 'Any' type.

Comment: @JaredSmith, I also tried `typing.Literal`, but I don't really like the mechanic how it works. It does not hint that we need a field. Just tells us that `Expected type 'Consts', got 'Type[Consts]' instead ` in case we try `foo(Consts)` instead of `foo(Consts.const_1)`

Comment: @Mika What IDE/type checker are you using?

Comment: @InSync PyCharm with default settings (except docstring parsing. It's switched to Google docstrings)

Comment: Given that `dataclass` uses various class attributes to define `__init__` and all, I'm of the opinion that it should *remove* the class attributes from the resulting class, instead of leaving them behind. In your example, `Consts.const_0` is still define as the integer 0, but it should be removed. If you really want a class attribute in the resulting dataclass, the correct syntax is `const_0: ClassVar[int] = 0`, which prevents `dataclass` from using the class attribute to define a new field.

Comment: Is `foo` supposed to take one of the *constants*, or the entire type, as an argument? For `foo(Consts)`, a correct type hint would be `def foo(param: type[Consts]): ...`. If you want to pass a single *value*, like `foo(Consts.const_0)`, that's just `def foo(param: Consts): ...`

Comment: (Also, are you using `Enum` or `IntEnum` as the base class for `Consts`?)

Comment: @chepner I use Enum as the base class in the UPD section only. Also, thanks for such detailed answer!

Comment: Now that you think you should use `Enum`, what exactly is the question? How to type a function that accepts members of a certain `Enum` class? How to make type checkers emits better error messages for `foo(Consts)` when `foo()` accepts a member of the `Enum` class `Consts`? Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I think this is a case where the user needs to learn what the error message means, because it's pretty straightfoward. "Expected type 'Consts'" means the function expects a value of type `Consts`. "got 'Type[Consts]'"` means it received a value of type `Type[Consts]`, which is either the class `Consts` itself or a subclass of `Consts`.

Comment: Mika, are you expecting callers of `foo` to literally pass `Constants.FIELD` to your function like this `some_result = foo(Constants.FIELD)` or are you expecting them to pass an integer value `some_result = foo(1)` which should be a member of that pool of constants? Or something else?

Comment: @InSync, sure, I'll edit it soon. In addition, I've tested `foo(param: Consts)` and got the warning using this `foo(Consts.const_1)`. Warning looks like "Expected type Consts got int instead`. So,

Comment: @JaredSmith The first variant. I want to simplify the constant storing for user. So, user shoud pass actually `Const.FIELD` instead of a single integer. This will have the same mechanic, as a global variable usage, but I try to combine constants in logical groups by using dataclasses

Comment: @Mika posted an answer, if you have any questions about it please comment down there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an enum here rather than a dataclass:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class MyEnum(IntEnum):
    A = 1
    B = 2

def foo(x: MyEnum):
    if (x == 1):
        return '1 given'
    else:
        return 'whatever'

foo(MyEnum.A) # Ok
foo(1)        # Error 
foo('pizza')  # Error
```

Tested against pyright and mypy type-checkers (I don't use PyCharm, not sure if it's running one of those under the hood or something custom to JetBrains).

Comment: Looks like pure solution which i was looking for. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Mika glad you got what you needed!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for the *values*  and not Enum members, sometimes that simply is not possible at all. Keep in mind that typing is static, not runtime, in Python.
When you use `typing.Literal`, at some point in your source code you have to have actually hardcoded that value, so the type-checking mechanism can trickle it down to the point of your function call.

But if the value is being obtained from an external source, be it a configuration variable, a database, whatever, the typing system can't know about it in any way - it does not run the program.

I think the correct thing to do in this case is to actually work with `Enum` *members* - whenever you get your `int` from an external source, convert it to a proper enum member - and that can be statically checked normally.

To convert a "plain" Python value to an enum member, just call the Enum class with the value: `Consts(0)` - which will also provide you with a runtime check. If type hinting complains at this step, add marks so that it is ignored at static checking type.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanation. In my current case I need a static constants group, which will not be changed in runtime (that's why I use frozen classes) so I'm looking for a static typing.